# Send method of FB.ui does not show multiple recipients

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created an app in Facebook app center and wanted to use this code for sending a message to multiple users. I checked my code in Javascript test console and worked properly but when pasted in my page it just showed the first recipient.

```
<script>
    var  arr = [];
    arr.push(4);
    arr.push(5);
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        FB.ui(
             {
                 method: 'send',
                 to: arr ,
                 link: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apadana",
                 picture: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Takhteh_Jamshid.jpg/200px-Takhteh_Jamshid.jpg",
                 description:"test me",
                 display: 'iframe'
             },
             function (param) {
                 if (!param.success){
                    // do smthing
                 }
                 else{
                      //throw Err
                 }
            });
         });
```

And also I initiated by these paramethers:

```
appid = '370960029693800';
channelurl = 'localhost';

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: appid,
        channelUrl: channelurl,
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true  

    });
```

As I said it works in javascript test console and seems something is wrong in initialization part. Please advise me which part of codes is wrong.

Comment: The [documentation page for the Send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/#params) clearly speaks of the parameter value as _“a user ID or username of a recipient.”_ – _singular_ instead of _plural_ for a reason, because you pre-selecting more than one person to send something to might be a little spammy perhaps …

Comment: I don't know how it can not be a spammy thing, because in my form, user might select some friends from a list and send a message to them. I found this (http://www.fbrell.com/saved/b4620e6c5533a1f4650b5b818ca01bea) example which works fine.